# Structure padding reliability

Tags: c, dll, dllimport

In C and C++ we are taught to treat structure padding as compiler-specific and so we avoid depending on it for things like serialization.

On the other-hand, we rely on consistent structure-padding whenever we link to 3rd party dynamic libraries or shared objects.

Let's take an example from `<windows.h>`:

```
typedef struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
  DWORD  nLength;
  LPVOID lpSecurityDescriptor;
  BOOL   bInheritHandle;
} SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, *PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, *LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;

HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  _In_opt_  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_      SIZE_T                 dwStackSize,
  _In_      LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_opt_  LPVOID                 lpParameter,
  _In_      DWORD                  dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_opt_ LPDWORD                lpThreadId
);
```

We shouldn't care which compiler was used to create Kernel32.dll, but compiler-defined structure padding means that if a different compiler was used, then Kernel32.dll may de-reference the `_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` pointer differently from how our application packed it.

- Could I get an explanation of why it's possible to pass structure pointers to third party DLLs while being agnostic to their structure padding?
- Does the same rationale work for dynamically loaded DLLs/SOs (using `LoadLibrary` or `dlopen`)?
- Does all of this concern go away if we use `#pragma pack`?
- If so, would `#pragma pack` be a reliable solution for structure serialization?

Comment: The winapi headers go through a great deal of trouble to ensure that this can't go wrong.  Partly visible in your snippet, it is not just void* but LPVOID, not just unsigned but DWORD.  Etcetera, nailing down a common type system is key.  Lots of structures used in the winapi have a field that stores the structure size, extra insurance and resilience against design changes.  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES does, note the nLength field.  And yes, lots of #pragma packs.

Comment: *On the other-hand, we rely on consistent structure-padding whenever we link to 3rd party dynamic libraries or shared objects.* A well-designed interface won't be dependent on the specifics of structure padding....

Comment: @AndrewHenle Does this mean that when you design an interface, it's bad practice to expect a user-initialized structure or structure pointer to be passed?  I often see libraries will allocate the memory for a structure, and then expect the pointer returned as a handle whenever methods are called.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Denying yourself the option of using structures when designing OS libraries isn't a great idea

Comment: @Stewart *Does this mean that when you design an interface, it's bad practice to expect a user-initialized structure or structure pointer to be passed?* It certainly is a bad practice if that structure's layout can change because of different command-line compiler arguments such as optimization levels.  GCC is pretty good at *not* providing such options.  Other compilers, not so much.

Comment: @Andrew If you'd been in charge of designing Win32, or the equivalent APIs on Linux you'd not have used any structs. You'd need to think through all the implications I suspect. Then you'd realise you were wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see you've never had to debug and fix a system where compiler command-line options changed structure padding. *ANY* system where user-controlled compiler command-line options can change structure layouts is "bad practice".  Interesting also that you're claiming the Win32 and Linux/POSIX APIs are "well-designed".

Comment: @AndrewHenle well, that's not something that happens with well written headers. Still, if you want to avoid using structs go ahead. Is that what you do? You never use structs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a language perspective you are quite correct. Padding and layout of structures is an implementation detail and the compiler is free to make its own choices.

In practise however, for a compiler to be useful on any specific platform, it must adhere to the platform ABI. If anyone attempted to produce a compiler that did not adhere to the platform ABI it would be utterly useless.

Because of this, you are safe to assume that any compiler that you use will be compatible with the platform ABI. You won't find any viable compiler that does not.

Comment: Interesting.  So structures can actually be serialized as long as the serialized form remains on the same platform.  This means it's find to do, but can't be relied on for network communications because you can't guarantee the source/target platform ABI matches your own.  (Of course you can't serialize anything with a pointer, but that's a different subject).

Comment: With the additional proviso that the process architecture is not changed. Structure layout will differ on 32 and 64 bit platforms. Anyway, you don't want to blit structures over the network, or to disk. So there's not really much point reasoning about it in my view.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to blit structures to disk?

Comment: Because they'll be full of padding and endianness issues when you have more than one architecture.